# create database in script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my Rails application development, I would like to write a script to create **a new database** and **a table** in the new database (I am using MySQL), so that I can later run the script like following:

```
rails runner db/scripts/data_mover.rb
```

But I do not know how to do it in ruby code or Rails way...Anyone can provide some hint or sample?

Comment: Just do what you do in migration

Comment: How? I need to create a new database, not only table

Answer (score 2):

write the code in a class, and place the file under `app/models`, such as `app/models/data_mover.rb'

```
class DataMover
  def self.run
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("CREATE DATABASE somedatabase")

    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
     :adapter  => "mysql",
     :host     => "localhost",
     :username => "myuser",
     :password => "mypass",
     :database => "somedatabase"
    )

    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.create_table :sometable do |t|
      #...
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can run `rails runner 'DataMover.run'` to create databases and tables.